# Middle School Level - Probability

Tags: probability

If you have 3 boxes and 7 coins fall in randomly, what is the probability that 3 coins fall into the first box?

My theory is that if you put one coin into each box until you have a remainder, by using modulus, you get `box%coins = x`. And then divide by the number of boxes to get the actual probability `box%coins = x/boxes`

This gives `1/3` as the probability in the case of 3 boxes and 7 coins. Is this correct?

Also, does it work for any number of boxes and coins?

Comment: Are the probabilities of falling into box1, box2, box3 equal (hence $\frac{1}{3}$) for each coin? If so then you are dealing with binomial distribution with parameters $n=7$ and $p=\frac{1}{3}$ (success if the coin falls in box1).

Comment: The answer is $\binom{7}{3}(1/3)^3 (2/3)^4$, not close to your idea.

Answer (score -1):

There are $9 \choose 2$ ways seven coins can fall into three boxes, and $5 \choose 1$ ways for four coins to fall into two boxes, so the probability is
$$
{5\choose1}/{9\choose2}={5\over36}
$$

Comment: Please point out the error if downvoting.